# Android Studio cannot run standalone Java applications?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

*(There on SO are similar unanswered questions though. Since I had worked a lot on this issue, so asked again with more experiences. Please don't close.)*

If you run a test application (with main method) in Android Studio, an error will be reported:

```
 SourceSet with name 'test' not found.
```

I tried removing the *-Test* suffix from the class name, and also tried moving the Java source file to the *main/* directory, but neither worked, thrown the similar error:

```
 SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

I googled a lot, but none of them worked.

The most confusing thing is that it was normal before, even if the class name ends with *-Test*.

At the same time, I have two computers, a laptop and a desktop computer, both running Debian 10. The strangest thing is that it is completely normal on the desktop, but failed the laptop. And failed and failed again after clean rebuilds.

I have tried upgrading Android Studio from 4.0 to 4.0.1, and tried reinstalling it entirely, no luck.

I have compared *$HOME/.gradle/* (it's very large, about ~8G), and checked the very detailed difference of the two installations on my laptop and desktop systems, there's no point of subtle difference. No clue at all.

Some people say it's impossible to run standalone applications in Android Studio, and recommends NetBeans.

*mighty-blob answered: ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/d27x8d/cant_run_very_basic_file_sourceset_with_name_main/))*

> I believe the Android developers took out the ability to run standalone java in the Studio (which creates its own default 'hello world' every time you open a new project).
>
> For standalone java go for netbeans.

That's not true, since I did run it and used to before.

REALLY weird.